# is there any picker like this in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

[i couldn't find any thing to have icon an text together in placeholder and label of items]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzOxe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one is more accurate for your design.

https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu

Comment: it was just what i was looking for. but how can i make the waper to open top of the trigger?

Comment: I could not understand what do you want?

Comment: i want to open menu on top of trigger text. i couldn't find out how

Answer (score 0):

This picker can render icon as your need just render your icon inside the render options

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-picker

Comment: it helped me a lot but i couldn't set  image to place holder

Comment: @Sirvahid your issue fixed or not? if not then share a snack.

Answer (score 0):

I used react native popup menu as my friend said and it worked after I used this code:

```
<MenuOptions customStyles={{optionsContainer:{marginVertical:-60}}}  >
```